# Is syntax keyword case sensitive?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to modify the plugin https://github.com/jaxbot/semantic-highlight.vim to highlight variables of differing case with different colours.

Some example configuration the plugin generates:

```
execute hi! def _semantic0 guifg=#9CD8F7
execute hi! def _semantic1 guifg=#F5FA1D
execute syn keyword _semantic0 json
execute syn keyword _semantic1 JSON
```

For the above, both `json` and `JSON` are highlighted with the same colour.

Is `syntax keyword` case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is, from the documentation:

> And a keyword with matching case always goes before a keyword with ignoring case.

see: [`:h syn-define`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syn-define)

Comment: I just tried the plugin with `:syntax off` and it worked as expected, must be something elsewhere interfering. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying this right now. And it seems to be case sensitive for neovim.